# I'd like to make 'Excel Connection Manager' in SSIS read every time diffrent file names in every time"Dynamic file name"

Tags: ssis

### Heading ##I Faced a little issue in SSIS in Excel connection manager this issue is :

```
 I moved and renamed excel sheet file in this name"CMP_20140309134003.xlsx" but in the day
 after and after it will come in diffrent name in every time like that
 "CMP_201403010134003.xlsx"
 so i faced an error in "Ecel Connection Manager" because the connection manager has
 a specific file name but i tried to creat variable for :
 1-file_path    C:\CMP_20140309134003.xlsx
 2-file_ext     *.xlsx
 3-folder_path  C:\
 and declare these variables in for each loop container and excel connection
 properties but faced the error 

 Is this any way to talk the source.xlsx name and put it into a variable to declare
 it into connection expression.

 so please how i can make the excel connection manager read diffrent file name
 in every time
 Any Suggestions??! :)
```

Comment: you can put it in a folder say c:\CMP\ and load whatever xlsx file is there regardless the name.

Comment: i made that but the problem is in the folder because the files will remove to another path with new name and will load another files in diffrent name in the same folder automatically

Answer (score 3):

1. In the for each loop container select 'Variable Mappings'
2. Map the name of the path and file name to a user variable
3. Right click in the connection manager and select 'Properties'
4. Click on 'Expressions' and then the ellipsis
5. Select 'ExcelFilePath' from the Property dropdown menu
6. Click on the ellipsis in column Expression
7. Select the name of the variable where you hold the path/filename

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excel Connection Manager properties [connection string] cannot be written to the property

Comment: @user3143565 Don't use ConnectionString use ExcelFilePath

Comment: it's working now Bro. but this file after load it in the database it will remove, what about the other files in the same structure but different names

Comment: I added some images to illustrate the process better. I'm creating a variable @FilePath in the for each loop which I then use in the Connection Manager; if it's set in this way, it should work for any xlsx file in the folder, regardless the name.